# Jquery: Conditional type logic

Tags: jquery, forms, selecteditem

I am trying to have two conditional type logic select option values. I have them working but when I select one the other erases itself which is not the desired effect.  I would like each to work independently of each other.

Here is my jquery:

```
 $("#00NK0000001wHIH").change(function() {
      var value = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("name");
      var theDiv = $(".is" + value);

      theDiv.slideDown().removeClass("hidden");
      theDiv.siblings('[class*=is]').slideUp(function() {
          $(this).addClass("hidden");
       });
  });
$("#00NK0000001n3SA").change(function() {
     var value = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("name");
     var theDiv = $(".is" + value);

     theDiv.slideDown().removeClass("hidden");
     theDiv.siblings('[class*=is]').slideUp(function() {
        $(this).addClass("hidden");
     });
});
```

[Here is my jsFiddle for you to play with.](http://jsfiddle.net/justawebbie/tYvQ8/1296/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using "siblings" and all of them are siblings, simply wrap all thats related to 00NK0000001wHIH inside a div and all should work.

```
<body>
<div><!--add a div here-->
  <div class="selectContainer">
...
<!--then end it here--> 
</div>
  <br />
  <div class="row" style="padding: 0;">
    <label class="small">Country</label>
```

Comment: I figured it was something so simple like that but was at a loss. Thank you so much devzero for your help.